# How to find lineage between SSAS (Tabular Model) and SQL database

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have 20+ tabular cubes with 300+ dimensions and was hoping to find - if there is some automated way to find what is the source for this dimension

Yes manually, I can get into **Tabular model > Table Properties** and can find what view and table are used to populate dimension. However not practically possible to get for 300+ dimensions.

And yes, I know some 3rd party provider such as **SQL Sentry** has some tools which can find that lineage.

But just wondering, is there any **SSAS DMVs** or any other script which can give these details?

Much appreciated for all your help

> **Note: Environment is On-Prem Microsoft SQL 2016 suite (SQL DB, SSAS and SSIS)**

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility level 1200 or above Tabublar models the `QueryDefinition` column of the `$SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS` DMV will show the source SQL statement for either each partition, or the entire dimension/fact table if it isn't partitioned.  In the event that a full table or view name is used (instead of a query) the full `SELECT` statement will be displayed with the object name.  This can be queried from either SSMS by connecting to the SSAS server and opening a new MDX/DAX query window or another tool such as Dax Studio.  This DMV is specific to whatever model you're connected to, as opposed to the whole SSAS instance.  In the example below the `Name` column is the name of the dimension from the model.  Since `Name` is a keyword it will need to be enclosed in brackets.

```
SELECT QueryDefinition FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS WHERE [Name] = 'DimensionName'
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.  And yes it provides view names and queries that we have used in dimensions.  However doesn't provide with Tabular Dimension name.    For example:  It gives Dimension name as **VW_Suppliers** by querying TMSCHEMA_Partitions while in Tabular we are calling as DimSupplier.

Comment: I have noticed by querying $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS, we are getting ID and TableID. And I think , TableID would indicate Dimension Name, so is there any other DMV which can provide Dimension Name in Tabular and Dim Name Alias

Comment: The "Name" column in $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS is the name the dimension/fact table.  If this it is partitioned, then the name of each partition will be in this column.  If it helps, try SELECT * to see all the columns.