# process table from SSAS tabular in tsql, and get back number of rows transferred (inserted)

Tags: t-sql, ssas-tabular

I would like to process the table from a SSAS Tabular model individually through a TSQL Script

I've found the way to do it, but now I'm missing a way to get back the number of rows updated... When doing it over the gui (ssms), it gives back that number, now I'd like to do the same...

```
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @Command = '
{
  "sequence": {
    "operations": [
      {
        "refresh": {
          "type": "dataOnly",
          "objects": [
            {
              "database": "test",
              "table": "D_Status",
            }
            ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
EXEC (@Command) AT [server\TABULAR];
```

I would expect a kind of rowcount, but this is not working (always return 1)

```
PRINT 'Record count: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @@ROWCOUNT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of rows shown in the GUI is the same as the total number of rows in the table (not just the updated / new rows).

So you could copy the queries from the cube and count the rows from them. You might want to use a DMV to get the queries behind all the tables like described here :[How to find lineage between SSAS (Tabular Model) and SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056248/how-to-find-lineage-between-ssas-tabular-model-and-sql-database)

Comment: Are you really able to get the number of rows over DMV ?
I was able to get the metadata, but no row count

Comment: I finally found it : 
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET('MSOLAP','DATASOURCE=.; Initial Catalog=test;',
    'SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_STORAGE_TABLES ')

Comment: What I meant was that you can get the query texts from a DMV and then you can run them separetly. Your solution is much better though!